# How to close the visual-force page opened as an iframe in the lighting view

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, lightning-experience

I am calling a visualforce page on click of a button (URL type) as displayed below:
[image]

On click of a button below page is opened.
[image]

Now I am not able to Close this page to go back to the record page.

I have tried

```
`function CloseWindow() {
        window.close();
     return false;

}

 <apex:commandButton value="Close" style="float:right" onclick="return navigateToParent();" rendered= "{!If(sObjectLabel == 'Asset Survey',true,false)}"/>`
```